# How to change the width of UITabBarItem?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, width, uitabbaritem

How to change the width of UITabBarItem?

I have an item with the title, that is wider than default item width. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just searched through the documentation and saw no method for adjusting the UITabBarItem's width.

A possible solution would be to place a view within the tab bar controller to load a custom UITabBarItem, that is the proper width.

Comment: I know I said that in my answer, but by placing a view with a custom width inside the tab bar (view within a view, not the tab bar linking to a view) you should be able to achieve your goal. I apologize if my original answer was ambiguous

Comment: If I place a view on tab bar how can I add a tab bar Item.

Comment: Read my answer, there's a solution from iOS7

Answer (score 19):

Solution for iOS7 and greater versions:

A new property has been introduced for UITabBar: **itemWidth**.

> Set the itemWidth to a positive value to be used as the width for tab
>   bar items when they are positioned as a centered group (as opposed to
>   filling the tab bar). Default of 0 or values less than 0 will be
>   interpreted as a system-defined width.

```
@property(nonatomic) CGFloat itemWidth NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0) UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR;
```

So you can do this in your AppDelegate:

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setItemWidth:WIDTH];
```

If you want to fill the whole UITabBar:

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setItemWidth:self.window.frame.size.width/NUMBER_OF_ITEMS];
```

[image: How to fill the UITabBar]

Comment: thanks for the great explanation including screenshots

Comment: it really works :) awesome. i have spent 8 hours to get the solution and this solve my problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution doesn't allow to customise width for specific item, only for all items altogether.

Answer (score 3):

You can change the spacing (and width) of the tab bar items by subclassing UITabBar and overriding its layoutSubviews method. You will find all tab bar buttons in the self.subViews array. Their class is the non-public UITabBarButton but they inherit from UIControl so you can identify all tab bar buttons checking if they are kind of UIControl class. Then all you need is to change the frame of the tab bar buttons.

Comment: And how will you assign custom `UITabBar` subclass to a `UITabBarController`?

Answer (score 1):

Found easier solution for swift if you subclass the UITabBarController
this will autofill the tab bar items evenly

```
self.tabBar.itemPositioning = .fill
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5**

```
UITabBar().itemWidth = self.window!.frame.size.width/5
```

Comment: Have you tested it?

I don't think it works to adjust the width of items.

Comment: @AshutoshShukla Yes, tested.

Comment: it doesn't work for me.  I believe you need to subclass the TabBar.