# UITabBarController extra space from top, bottom, leading, traling

Tags: ios, swift

Hello All i am creating Tab bar programmatically, in my functionality there need to be selected tab filled with custom color, i have achieved this so far using below code and the following output see screenshot.

```
tabBarController.tabBar.selectionIndicatorImage = UIImage.imageWithColor(color: colors.AppSkyBlue, size: tabBarItemSize).resizableImage(withCapInsets: UIEdgeInsets(top: 1, left: 1, bottom: 1, right: 1), resizingMode: .stretch)
```

[image]

**Clearly see the white space be around selected tab, ho do i remove this from all side.** Any help would be appreciated well.

Comment: How about adding a subview on top of your tabbar, with background color same as tabbar color, so it blends with it., written a simple code snippet for the same.

Comment: see this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33868139/how-to-make-uitabbar-selection-indicator-image-fill-the-whole-space/34510070#34510070

Answer (score 1):

You Could simple add a subview on top of UITabBar and give the bg color same as the color of tab bar - so it blends with it

```
var lineView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width:tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.width, height: 1))
lineView.backgroundColor = UIColor.grey
tabBarController.tabBar.addSubview(lineView)
```

This is one of the options.